# Is there some way to bring the attention of the mouse to the foreground window?

Tags: wayland, sway

When using Sway 1.7, sometimes when I open another application's window (e.g. evince's window that shows a pdf file) after having opened one (e.g. Google Chrome browser's window showing a webpage), the mouse still implicitly stays working on the earlier application's window which is now hidden under the new application's window.

- when hovering the mouse over different controls in the foreground window, the shape of the cursor changes not according to the controls in the foreground window, but those in the background one.
- When clicking the mouse over a control in the foreground window, it triggers an event of whatever control in the background one, which happens to be underneath.

When the problem happens, is there some way to refresh the windows, or bring the attention of the mouse to the foreground window?